# Rails TemplateMissing when exception occurs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code segment

```
def range
  respond_to do |format|
    if params[:start] && params[:end]
      begin
        dstart = Time.parse(params[:start])
        dend = Time.parse(params[:end])
      rescue => e
        format.json { render :json => { :status => :unprocessable_entity, :error => e.message }} and return
      end
  ...
```

And it works totally fine and makes it to the stuff at the bottom...

```
...
format.json { render :json => { :status => :ok, :posts => @res.to_json(:only => [:date, :content, :user_id]) } }
  else
format.json { render :json => { :status => :unprocessable_entity, :error => "must have a _start_ and _end_ date" } }
...
```

The problem is when an exception occurs and the `rescue` section is called, Rails does not respond with json but instead tells me "Template Missing." Is something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0):

D'oh, turns out I don't need the `format.json` bit. Why, exactly, though?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example regarding show action to understand the error

```
class ModelsController
.
.
  def show
    @model = Model.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

In this case, if the request is of type html then rails by convention searcher for a file 
app/views/models/show.html.erb.

But if the request is of type js then rails will search for app/views/models/show.js.erb.
If these files does not exist then rails will throw template missing error

so if you are only responding to json then you can do

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json do
    begin 
    ..  
    rescue
      render :json => { }
    end 
end
```